# I cant seem to get the fucntion to find the file in the directory. Is it a parsing error?

Tags: lua

```
function file_exists(name)
    local f=io.open("test.txt","r")
    if f~=nil then io.close(f) logMsg("File exists") return true else logMsg("No file") return false end
 end
```

I have created a file named test.txt in the same directory as this lua file, however, I can not get it to find it.

I've tried adding the following.

```
function file_exists(test.txt)
    local f=io.open("test.txt","r")
    if f~=nil then io.close(f) logMsg("File exists") return true else logMsg("No file") return false end
 end
```

Got an error message stating expected ") near ."

also tried it in quotes and get  or '..' expected near "test.txt"

Truly at a loss for this one.

Comment: If your wondering about the logMsg its a fly with lua cmd

Comment: Your first approach looks fine (even if messy; you don't use the name parameter). Check what your current working directory is. Note that a file may exist without you having permission to read it. Your second approach is very weird - you're writing `test.txt` in the parameter list? That's a pretty glaring syntax error.

Comment: Shouldn't Io.open use the directory the file is in since Lua does not natively have the ability to define directories?

Comment: [`io.open`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.open)([source](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/liolib.c.html#io_open)) is a very thin wrapper around the C function [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen). The semantics for the *filename* argument ultimately depend on your OS, but generally paths are relative to the *current working directory*, which is the directory in which the program was executed - not necessarily the directory where the program is stored.

Comment: How are you using this function / how are you running Lua?

Comment: I'm using vscode to keep track of and edit the code. I'm using Xplane to run the code, since the actual program is not recognized by vs code.